# How to bring up an alarm on top of television

Tags: android-tv, smart-tv, google-tv

I was wondering whether it is possible to install an app that brings an alarm into the foreground while the television is playing on Android TVs.

I ask, because, this morning, the television, and other media, were on, and I got distracted.

If an alarm had been brought into the foreground to remind me of what I had to do I would have been able to complete my task, and complete it on time.

Can you please answer me, and tell me if there is a way to install such an app, and make it work (including, installing an auxiliary alarm device (as can be done with Chromecast), to work, as an alarm, on top of the television.

By including the alarm in the television (hopefully, I can just install an app), I am ensuring the alarm goes off, and it cannot be moved away, from, the television screen (which is where is is needed).

Also, important, that a separate volume be present, to be set and override, the current settings.

But it is important that the alarm is displayed and stays there, because, in this way, you are also, reminded, visually.

Thank you for your answers.

Thank you for letting me know how to accomplish the task at hand.

Thank you.